# CSS Column Height Fill

Tags: html, css, flexbox

thanks for taking a look at my question. I am new to CSS and html and am attempting to create a skeleton web page. I am attempting to create a page with flexbox it has two SIDE BY SIDE rows, each with a nested column. The issue arises when I try to stretch the columns to the "parent height/number of columns" this is proving to be a difficult issue that has no easy solution (at least from what. for example, a column with two articles would need a height of 50% of the parent div, so the column fully fills it. with 3 items the articles must be 33% height to make the column fill the row.

Example illustration (2 rows, the left with one column item, the right with two.

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
O--text--O---text--O
O--text--O--empty--O
O--text--O--empty--O
O--text--OOOOOOOOOOO
O--text--O---text--O
O--text--O--empty--O
O--text--O--empty--O
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

How it currently looks:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
O--text--O --text--O
O--text--OOOOOOOOOOO
O--text--O --text--O
O--text--OOOOOOOOOOO
O--text--O--empty--O
O--text--O--empty--O
O--text--O--empty--O
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Can i do this with Java, and if so; Would somebody be able to lend me their wisdom?

My current code is:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  /*height: auto; */
  position: relative;
}

section {
  background-color: #cccccc20;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
}

.col {
  column-fill: balance;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.article {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/structure.css">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body class="container">

  <section>
    <div class="row">

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="article">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="article">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you've not described any "issue" that arises, what's the problem and what's the desired look?

Comment: of course, an edited version is posted up top; thanks for the time!

Comment: sounds like 2 columns with rows? Maybe use a table?

Comment: the reason i have tried to stay away form tables is I'm trying to create a framework that can be easily modified for most websites; and from what ive read, tables are slow, and difficult to manage on larger sites.

Answer (score 3):

Using `flex-box` makes your goal lot more easier.

> I deleted the margins, position property(found on the `section` element with value of `absolute`), the `display`  property from the `.article` elements(try to avoid tables they are not responsive), the selectors are based on the current `HTML` structure, and I set the `box-sizing` property to `border-box` for all the elements on the demo.

Here's a working demo:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 500px;
  /*height: auto; */
  position: relative;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cccc20;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.row .col {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow: auto; /* adds scroll bars if the content is more than the element's height */
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="row">Some content here</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="article">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="article">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) about `box-sizing` property.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) about `flexbox`.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will look into this and hopefully have a solution soon!

Comment: @ChristianPotts Did my answer helped you ?

Comment: I upvoted you answer btw, even though it wasn't written as specifed (in Java)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use css `grid-area` property:

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: main;
  height: 300px;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: right1;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: right2;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'main right1' 'main right2';
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: #DCE1E7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid Layout</h2>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Main</div>
  <div class="item2">Right1</div>
  <div class="item3">Right2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to be able to add articles and have them flex into the container automatically, whereas this is more of a layout approach "With 3 items the articles must be 33% height to make the column fill the row."

Comment: `display: grid` isn't well supported among browsers.